# How can I catch `unexpected $ after open inline math \(` in auctex?

Tags: auctex, flycheck, flymake

Overleaf generates following warning message for tex files: `unexpected $ after open inline math \(`.

Is it possible to catch this warning message in AUCTex as well?

Example would be: `\( ... $ ... \)`

```
\(a_{s}$ and $h_{d}\)
       ^
       |___ unexpected $ after open inline math \(`
```

Note that when you try to type `$`  in between `\( \)` auctex does not allow and gives `Math mode started with ‘\(’ cannot be closed with dollar` warning message. But if you just paste `\( $ \)` into the buffer it does not give any warning message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Interesting how can I enable lacheck?

***How can you afford NOT to read the `AucTeX` manual? Make it a habit to read the manual when you are relying on some tool very heavily***

***Check for syntax errors in `tex` buffers using `lacheck` and `flymake`***

[image: Check for syntax errors in tex buffers using lacheck and flymake]

```lisp
(info "(auctex) Checking")
```

### https://emacsdocs.org/docs/auctex/Checking

File: auctex.info, Node: Checking, Next: Control, Prev: Debugging, Up: Processing

## 4.4 Checking for problems

Running TeX or LaTeX will only find regular errors in the document, not examples of bad style.  Furthermore, description of the errors may often be confusing.  The utilities `lacheck` and `chktex` can be used to find style errors, such as forgetting to escape the space after an abbreviation or using `...` instead of `\ldots` and other similar problems.  You start `lacheck` with `C-c C-c Check <RET>` and `chktex` with `C-c C-c ChkTeX <RET>`.  The result will be a list of errors in the `*compilation*` buffer.  You can go through the errors with ``` C-x \``  ( ```next-error`, note (emacs)Compilation::), which will move point to the location of the next error.

Alternatively, you may want in-buffer notation.  AUCTeX provides support for this using the Flymake package in Emacs 26 or newer (note (Flymake)Using Flymake:: for details).  To enable, call `M-x flymake-mode <RET>` in the buffer or enable it in all buffers by adding this to your init file:

```lisp
(add-hook `LaTeX-mode-hook #`flymake-mode)
```

Note that AUCTeX currently only provides support for using `chktex` as the flymake backend.

Each of the two utilities `lacheck` and `chktex` will find some errors the other doesnot, but `chktex` is more configurable, allowing you to create your own errors.  You may need to install the programs before using them.

**You can get `lacheck` from URL:https://www.ctan.org/pkg/lacheck and `chktex`  from URL:https://www.ctan.org/pkg/chktex.  TeX Live contains both.**

**~$ apt-cache show lacheck**

Package: lacheck
Version: 1.26-17
Installed-Size: 76
Maintainer: Davide G. M. Salvetti salve@debian.org
Architecture: amd64
Replaces: auctex (<< 9.7l-1)
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14)
Recommends: texlive-latex-base
Suggests: auctex
Breaks: auctex (<< 9.7l-1)
Description-en:

**Simple syntax checker for LaTeX**

LaCheck is a simple syntax checker for LaTex that is based on a single-pass lexical scanner. This makes clear that there are a lot of LaTeX problems this program cannot find, although it will find most simple mistakes.  Complex macro packages may, however, make it completely unusable.  .  This program was bundled with AUCTeX once upon a time and is best known from there.

---

**~$ apt-cache show chktex**

Package: chktex
Version: 1.7.6-5
Installed-Size: 225
Maintainer: Thorsten Alteholz debian@alteholz.de
Architecture: amd64
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.33), libpcre2-posix3 (>= 10.34), libtinfo6 (>= 6)
Description-en:

**Finds typographic errors in LaTeX**

ChkTeX finds typographic errors in LaTeX documents:

- Supports over 40 warnings.
- Supports `\input` command; both TeX and LaTeX version. Actually includes the files. `TEXINPUTS''`-equivalent search path.
- Intelligent warning/error handling. The user may promote/mute warnings to suit his preferences. You may also mute warnings in the header of a file; thus killing much unwanted garbage.
- Supports both LaTeX 2.09 and LaTeX2e.
- Flexible output handling. Has some predefined formats and lets the user specify his own format. Uses a `printf()` similar syntax. `lacheck` compatible mode included for interfacing with the AUC-TeX Emacs mode.

Comment: Can we set `la-lacheck` as default checker at the config ?

Answer (score 1):

AUCTeX doesn't have a code parser which checks your code all the time.  The case where you get the warning message `Math mode started with ‘\(’ cannot be closed with dollar` is due to the function `TeX-insert-dollar` which is invoked when you insert a `$`.

If you want on-the-fly syntax checking then I suggest you take a look at tools like `flymake` and/or `flycheck`.

Comment: Should I configure `flycheck` for this? I think it is on but it does not detect this

Comment: @alper - Can't tell since I haven't `flycheck` installed.  I briefly tried `lacheck` as a linter with AUCTeX which recognizes the issue and `chktex` which doesn't.  So it seems it's a `chktex` issue.

Comment: Interesting how can I enable `lacheck`? Should I open a issue at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chktex ?

Comment: @alper - If you have the binary `lacheck` installed, you can try it in your .tex file with `C-c C-c Check RET` (or from the `Command` menu) and get a buffer with the results.

Comment: `C-c C-c` returns `TeX-command-master`on my end

Comment: @alper - I don't understand you last comment; `C-c C-c` runs `TeX-command-master` and then you can choose a command.  Try `TAB` in the minibuffer to get a list of candidates.  Or choose one from the `Command` menu.

Comment: Ah sorry it was different key binding on my end: `flycheck-select-checker (C-c ! s)`